# Не читается файл открытый с режимом 'w+'

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система

Есть файл `file.txt` с содержанием

> Текст

Открываю с помощью команды `file = open('file.txt', 'w+')`. Далее: `file.write('Something')`. Далее пытаюсь считать информацию из файла. `info = file.read()`. Теперь `info` равно `''`. Что не так?

Comment: Всё так. При открытии в режиме `w+` если файл существует, то он обнуляется (содержимое стирается).

Comment: @zed не все обстоятельства указал, сейчас изменю вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы считать файл с самого начала - необходимо переместить каретку в 0 положение:

```
file.seek(0)
```

Затем уже читайте файл методом `.read()`

Также режим `'w+'` перезапишет файл, старое содержимое получить не получится.